# how can video clips be merged in Corel Video Studio Pro x7?

Tags: video-editor

Can video clips be combined or merged in Corel Video studio pro 7? Can anyone describe how it could be done.  I am using Windows 7 home edition.  I have already examined the that may have already have your answer>

Comment: Welcome to Video Production. The question as it is is probably too broad to get a good answer: please specify what you mean by "merged".

Comment: When I say merged I mean combine one or more video clips into ONE video clip. This can easily be done in Sony's "CLICK-TO-DVD"

Comment: "Combine" is as broad as "merge". Do you mean make the clips play one after the other, or some sort of compositing where you see both at the same time - e.g. picture in picture, or a transparent overlay?

Comment: By merge, I mean COMBINE, for instance, ten video clips into ONE video clip!  A one hour DV video tape may have 300 to 400 hundred clips, which is difficult to work with, and more difficult to view on a timeline!

Comment: So you mean play one after the other.

Comment: I mean COMBINE, for instance, ten video clips into ONE video clip to be played one after the other. Therefore, if have 300 clips, I might want to combine the so that I have only 50 clips to work with on the timeline!

Comment: You don't seem to understand. When the clips are COMBINED or merged do you want the original videos playing **all at once** or **one after the other**? Don't just say COMBINED again or I will break something, I swear.

Comment: If you are familiar with Sony's CLICK-TO-DVD , on the storybook view, clips can be combined, original clips maintained. COMBINED clips can be played in viewer and as a last step, cut to a DVD. Thus, if you have some hundreds of clips in an hour DV tape, they can be combined for viewing into any number of combined clips for viewing! I am simply asking if this can be done in COREL , which it looks like it CANNOT!

Comment: I think the question is how do you merge two video clips into one. So that when you click on the video click you can make changes to the entire clip rather than the two split clips. I want to adjust the audio for about 15 clips all at once. The best way to do this would be to merge all the 15 clips into one. So that you are only working with one clip.

Comment: There are two problems here, one is that the terms "combine" and "merge" are not technical terms and do not have a clear meaning in a video editing context.  Continuing to use the same terms does not make things any clearer.  That said, I think I understood the meaning that you want to have subclips that are the result of editing multiple clips together.  The concept is nested timelines in something like Premiere.  Nested clips might be a more clear term to use in that case.

Comment: The second problem is that this is a more pro focused site and thus very few of our main users have ever used something like Corel Video Studio which I'd never even heard of prior to this question.  That limits the ability to answer the question pretty severely beyond simply checking documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how its done.
Create a new folder.Select the film clips you want to merge together all at once and import them into the folder you created. Drag the clips into the storyboard view and its done.
Check this out :

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Corel Video Studio Pro and, for that matter, I hadn't even heard of it prior to this question despite being familiar with Corel products in general, however a quick look at the table of contents of the documentation does not seem to indicate that there is a way to nest projects.  This is typically how subclips are created.

If I had to guess, the reason for the feature to be missing in a presumably "higher end" mid-range editing system than a basic DVD creation tool is because of the added complexity of what you can do with a clip.  Nesting of unrendered timelines presents a number of challenges due to figuring out processing order and how to most efficiently deal with the assets, especially when nesting may become multiple levels deep.  The feature is typically found on higher end editing systems like Premiere, Final Cut and Avid, but seems to be more rarely found in mid-range solutions or may have limited support.

Comment: Just to clarify, Vegas can nest timelines.

Comment: @Mulvya - how is it done?  I could not find anything in the documentation about it nor was I able to figure it out after trying for around an hour.  I'd be happy to be wrong about that, but I was not able to find a way to do so.  Perhaps they added it in a newest version?

Comment: It's an old feature. File -> Import -> Media -> Savedproject.veg. It'll show up in Project Media.

Comment: @mulvya very good to know. I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.